# How to save resualt image of run a query in c# webbrowser

Tags: c#, image, save

In a project of C# I used a web browser.
In the browser I navigate a URL which runs a query in it and an image is shown.
My address is same to that:

```
http:\\web.org\subquery?11
```

How to show this in a picture box?

Comment: you extract the URL of the image and download it.

Comment: Dont work it.i do it

Comment: I do it but not worked....pic.imagelocation=webbrowser1.url.tostring()